# Bash: delete word ahead of cursor

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

Consider the following bash command line, where ^ denotes the cursor location:

```
svn commit -m very/long/path/to/some/file "[bug 123456] Fix the pixel issue"
              ^
```

I'd like to commit a different file with the same message. How can I delete the current word, from cursor location to the next space? Is there also a shortcut for backward deletion, form the cursor to the first space backwards?

**Update:** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> erases backwards, but which shortcut erases one word forward?

Comment: `Ctrl u` is an option for erasing from cursor location to beginning...

Comment: Try `alt + d`, that might be useful, when emacs editing mode is set.

Comment: @Mik how do you enable emacs mode?

Comment: @AdamMatan `set -o emacs` enables it, but it is usually the default; if not, you can put that line in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`, then source the file or reload the terminal. However, then the shortcuts you may be used to in vi mode won't be available, although ones such as ctrl+c will because they are not Bash shortcuts.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I answered similar question [on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71350/delete-whole-argument-in-current-bash-command-line/71810#71810):

> Bash has readline commands that aren't bound by default. You can find
>   them at reference:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands
>
> Command you are looking for is called "shell-backward-kill-word". You
>   have to select shortcut first. Let's use Crtl+p, since it's "previous
>   command" - same as up arrow.
>
> ```
> bind '"\C-p": shell-backward-kill-word'
> ```

The only difference is you have to use "shell-kill-word" command instead, since you want to delete forward.

There is also a "kill-word" command with <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> shortcut (try <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> if you don't have Meta key). It will delete only one part of path at once.

Comment: Alt-d works for me

Comment: Generally, in the world of keyboards where Meta doesn't exist, Alt = Meta.

Comment: I the world where you have many different keyboards, a convenient and fairly useful fact is that Esc as a prefix also acts as Meta.

Comment: In short, add e.g. this to your $HOME/.inputrc file:`"\ew": shell-kill-word`  , that will make Alt-w forward delete a word , much like CTRL-w backwards deletes a word (and unlike Alt-d which will forward delete but stop at e.g. a / or - and other characters)

Comment: @NateC-K "in the world of keyboards where Meta doesn't exist": which today is, more or less, the world?

Answer (score 15):

Tested both the <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on OSX Mavericks and they work there as well.

Comment: `Option + d` gives me ∂ on OSX

Comment: -1 OSX is not Ubuntu. Feel free to add a comment, but this is not an answer.

Comment: you have to first enable the checkbox "use option as meta key" in the terminal preferences (profiles -> keyboard tab -> checkbox)

Comment: `control + d` on mac Sierra

Comment: Both work on Ubuntu 18.04, Unity, gnome-terminal.

Comment: @IvanBalashov if you are using iterm set your let opt key as esc+ . Under Profiles >keys